# NSManagedObject changes reference in block

Tags: objective-c, core-data, objective-c-blocks

I have a NSManagedObject. In some cases when I access the object in a block is it faulted with a different pointer and I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash when I access the variables of the object.

Here is a simplified code:

```
+(void)updateObject:(NSManagedObject *)object{
        NSLog(@"Object %@", object);

[self requestUpdateFromDict:currentDict
                     succes:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
    {
       NSLog(@"Object %@", object);
       [doSomethingWith:object]
    }];
}
```

The output is for example:

```
Object <TestObject: 0x7f9fadab1bc0> (entity: TestObject; id: 0xd000000000040004 <x-coredata://5F27CBB5-800D-44B8-BB4B-99A0DE6962E4/TestObject/p1> ; data: {
    floatVar = "2.14";
    "int_32Var" = 99;
    "resource_uri" = "/test";
    stringVar = "Just resting.";
})
Object <TestObject: 0x7f9fad956680> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd000000000040002 <x-coredata://C9D50E1B-46E9-4C11-96BE-622281232D5B/TestObject/p1> ; data: <fault>)
```

The address of the object seems to have changed from 0x7f9fadab1bc0 to 0x7f9fad956680.

- when I put a break point at [doSomethingWith:object] and run "po
  0x7f9fadab1bc0" I get the same output as the first log entry.
- The objects didTurnIntoFault did not fire between the printing of the two log statements.
- This method is also run in a test and when I run the test alone it passes. When I run it together with the 3 other tests in the XCTestCase it fails. As part of the teardown a destroy the Core data store. This method however is not called during the running of the test (verified with breakpoints)

Answer (score 0):

Change the logging style. You are having same kind of message for both log. 
There might be chances of second method of updateObject might have been called from some other place in the code. Also its better to put some kind of lock when you use NSManagedContext.